# Interlaced uniform versus non-uniform hierarchy

Tags: complexity-classes, circuit-complexity, advice-and-nonuniformity, hierarchy-theorems, uniformity

Denote $\mathsf{uniform}$ class with prefix $\mathsf{u}$ and $\mathsf{non}$-$\mathsf{uniform}$ class with prefix $\mathsf{nu}$.

In following some non-trivial *standard* notion of *uniformity* (like $\mathsf{DLOGTIME}$-$\mathsf{uniform}$) is assumed.

> **Problem:**
>   Does
>   $$\mathsf{uTC}^i\mbox{ }{{{\underbrace{\subseteq}_{(1)}}\mbox{ }\mathsf{nuTC}^{i+k_i}\cap\mathcal C_{i}\subseteq}\mbox{ }}\mathcal C_{i}\subseteq\mbox{ }\mathcal C_{i+k_i}$$
>
> $$\mathsf{nuTC}^{i}\cap\mathcal C_{i+l_i}\mbox{ }{\underbrace{\subseteq}_{(2)}}\mbox{ }\mathsf{uTC}^{i+l_i}\subseteq\mathcal C_{i+l_i}$$
>   hold at any $i\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ for some $k_i\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}$ and some $l_i\in\Bbb N$ for any choice of complexity class $\mathcal C_{j}$ such that $\mathsf{uTC}^{j}\subseteq\mathcal C_{j}\subseteq\mathsf{EXPSPACE}$ holds?

$(1)$ should be true since technically any circuit produced by a deterministic turing machine can also be assumed to be part of *non-uniform* model and so $\mathsf{uTC}^{i}\subseteq\mbox{ }{\mbox{ }\mathsf{nuTC}^{i+k_i}\cap\mathcal C_{i}\subseteq\mbox{ }}\mathcal C_{i}$ should hold even with $k_i=0$ but again *uniformity* and *non-uniformity* makes it unclear.

It seems pretty trivial that $(2)$ should hold since greater depth circuits should be more expressive however *uniformity* puts a restriction on type of circuits that can be generated at depth $i+l_i$.

**Update:** Michael Cadilhac points that this problem is similar to asking whether *extensionally uniform* classes are contained in *intentionally uniform* ones where *extensionally uniform* is given in McKenzie's work http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.4072? If we go by analogy from there McKenzie's classes under consideration $\mathcal C_{i}$ would be much smaller than $\mathsf{uTC}^i$ when taken in context here and not applicable to current problem.

Comment: Why did you delete your previous question?

Comment: I cannot see why you did not just edit your previous question.  That seems completely overkill, especially since we had a conversation going with some other user (I couldn't see the name as the post was deleted).  In any case, you should probably point to the fact that you ask: "Are extensionally uniform classes in intentionally uniform ones?"

Comment: @Kaveh I observed that it seems to provide some kind of direct connection between uniform model and non-uniform models (if one is hard the should be hard if above post holds true)

Comment: For 2 see [this](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1982/).

Comment: @Kaveh thank you

Comment: @kaveh but there could be a much smaller intersecting class than NP?

Comment: @Kaveh 1 also seems open ended from your post there.