# $\mathsf{P} \ne \mathsf{P/poly} \cap \mathsf{NP}$?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, p-vs-np, advice-and-nonuniformity

Assuming $\mathsf{P} \ne \mathsf{NP}$ can we show $\mathsf{P} \ne \mathsf{P/poly} \cap \mathsf{NP}$? Obviously this would be the case if $\mathsf{P} \ne \mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{P/poly} \supset \mathsf{NP}$ but this is unlikely. This is also true under the assumption $\mathsf{P} \ne \mathsf{BPP}$, however AFAIK it is commonly believed $\mathsf{P} = \mathsf{BPP}$. Can we prove $\mathsf{P} \ne \mathsf{P/poly} \cap \mathsf{NP}$ under a weaker assumption? What evidence can be provided for/against? Is there a specific language which is believed to be in $\mathsf{P/poly} \cap \mathsf{NP}$ but not in $\mathsf{P}$?

Comment: related question: [Is $\mathsf{AC^0}/poly \cap \mathsf{NP}$ contained in $\mathsf{P}$?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1982/186)

Comment: also: [Is there a candidate for a natural problem in $\mathsf{P}/poly−\mathsf{P}$?](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1662/186)

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I realized that it was essentially the same as [Yuval Filmus’ answer](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1989#1989) in the first link which Kaveh gave.

Comment: You think maybe this question should be closed as a duplicate?

Comment: Squark, do the answers in the linked questions answer your question? If not then it would be nice if clarify the question and explain why they don't.

Comment: @Kaveh Yes, I think these answers are satisfactory, thank you